# Porting existing web app to mobile web app

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, mobile, web

I have a existing web application which is build using Html,javascript,CSS and jquery ui.
Now I want to port this app on smartphones and tablets.As I have cross platform need so i went for Phonegap.But the thing is I am confused what to use jquery-ui or jquery mobile.

After searching on internet found that jquery mobile is prefered for mobile web apps as jquery ui is quite heavy compared to jquery-mobile.But making use of jquery mobile will result in rework for me which I dont want due to limited time span.

1. So is there any other way by which i can port my existing web app on mobile with less efforts?
2. What will be the challenges if i use jquery-ui in mobile web app?

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

It seems logical to use JQuery Mobile for mobile apps. People will be surprised, if not annoyed, if you use a different version of JQuery.

If you're not using JQuery already, then the challenge to make your app JQuery compatible will be about the same for both versions.